# Inception v3 flowers_train using the checkpoint model

Tags: tensorflow

I have used the flowers_train script found here: [flowers_train.py](https://github.com/awslabs/deeplearning-benchmark/blob/master/tensorflow/inception/inception/flowers_train.py).

To retrain the existing inception v3 model on 10 new classes. The flowers_train script generates some checkpoint files of the format:

```
checkpoint                              model.ckpt-1030000.index
events.out.tfevents.1501217995.tron     model.ckpt-1030000.meta
model.ckpt-1020000.data-00000-of-00001  model.ckpt-1035000.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-1020000.index                model.ckpt-1035000.index
model.ckpt-1020000.meta                 model.ckpt-1035000.meta
model.ckpt-1025000.data-00000-of-00001  model.ckpt-1040000.data-00000-of-00001
model.ckpt-1025000.index                model.ckpt-1040000.index
model.ckpt-1025000.meta                 model.ckpt-1040000.meta
model.ckpt-1030000.data-00000-of-00001
```

The classify_image.py script is found [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/image/imagenet/classify_image.py).

It expects a .pb file, not a checkpoint file.

I've been pulling my hair over the past two weeks trying to figure out how to get from the checkpoint file to the `.pb` file so I can use the retrained model.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Comment: You can use the checkpoint file to run inference as well. If you want to freeze the graph, you can have a look at the code here:

 https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py

Comment: Here is a similar question with a good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42485004/using-inception-v3-checkpoint-file-in-tensorflow?rq=1

Comment: @Blackberry I have followed the following script [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/slim/export_inference_graph.py) to generate the **inception_v3_inf_graph.pb**

I then used the freeze_graph.py script as follows:

`bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph \
--input_graph=/tmp/inception_v3_inf_graph.pb \
--input_checkpoint=/mnt/scale_project/trained_model/training_dir/model.ckpt-1635000 \
--input_binary=true --output_graph=/tmp/frozen_inception_v3.pb \
--output_node_names=InceptionV3/Predictions/Reshape_1`
But got the error:
ValueError: No variables to save

Answer (score 0):

> Any ideas would be appreciated.

The code at https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining

> ```
> cd ~
> curl -LO http://download.tensorflow.org/example_images/flower_photos.tgz
> tar xzf flower_photos.tgz
>
> mkdir ~/example_code
> cd ~/example_code
> curl -LO https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/raw/master/examples/image_retraining/retrain.py
>
> python retrain.py --image_dir ~/flower_photos
> ```

produces the file `./output_graph.pb`.